# Image Splitter in android

Tags: android, image, android-studio

I am new to android.In my project, I try to split the image into chunks like (3*3 , 4*4, 5*5). but i have an issue like

```
`"FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION" and java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure from system.
```

I referred [this](http://androidattop.blogspot.in/2012/05/splitting-image-into-smaller-chunks-in.html) site but it shows error.

The above class has splitImage method which takes two arguments:
ImageView: The source image to split.
int: The number of smaller chunks to be formed from the source image.

**Here is the code:**

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.source_image);
splitImage(image, chunkNumbers);
```

splitImage Method,

```
private void splitImage(ImageView image, int chunkNumbers) {        
    ArrayList<Bitmap> chunkedImages = new ArrayList<Bitmap>(chunkNumbers);
    BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) image.getDrawable();
    Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
    Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), true);
    rows = cols = (int) Math.sqrt(chunkNumbers);
    chunkHeight = bitmap.getHeight()/rows;
    chunkWidth = bitmap.getWidth()/cols;
    int yCoord = 0;
    for(int x=0; x<rows; x++){
        int xCoord = 0;
        for(int y=0; y<cols; y++){
            chunkedImages.add(Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap, xCoord, yCoord, chunkWidth, chunkHeight));
            xCoord += chunkWidth;
        }
        yCoord += chunkHeight;
    }
    Intent intent = new Intent(ImageActivity.this, ChunkedImageActivity.class);
    intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("imagechunks", chunkedImages);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Issue:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.yoga.image_splitter, PID: 2674
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure from system at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity
    Caused by: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 3700628 bytes
    at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
```

Comment: You are trying to pass too much data through intent.

Comment: Is there any ways to solve this issue. Please help me.

Comment: Write the image to sdcard and pass its url rather than passing the image itself.